# Delete a key from all the cursors in redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

This is the way I have added the alert in redis. Now the problem is when we use zadd it automatically adds at any random cursors. What I want to achieve is to delete a specific key from all the cursors. The problem is I am not sure how many cursors there are and how I can iterate on all the cursors to delete the specific key.

```
redis_key = "component_list"
user_alert = "#{user_id}:#{friend_id}:#{user_code}"
redis.zadd(redis_key, ::Time.current.to_i, user_alert)


match_key = "abc_code"

alerts_arr = redis.zscan(redis_key, 0, match: "*#{match_key}*").last.map(&:first)

alerts_arr.each { |alert| redis.zrem(REDIS_KEY, alert) }
```

From the above code, it only deletes from the 0th cursors. But I want to delete it from all the cursors. Can someone help me with it?